# How to share state between Multiple windows of the same SwiftUI MacOS app

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want to share state between multiple windows of the same SwiftUI app on Mac.
According to the documentation, @State and @Stateobject are not shared, as my example shows.
What to do, to share state between the two windows.

```
@main
struct TM_window_TestApp_2: App {
  @State var state: String?
  @State var selectedInSub: Int?
  @StateObject var stateObject = SimpleStateObject()
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      VStack{
        SubView(selected: $selectedInSub)
        Text("\(selectedInSub == nil ? "nothing selected" : selectedInSub!.formatted())")
        Text("------------")
        Text("shared State: ??")
        Text(stateObject.s)
        Text("\(state == nil ? "nil" : state!)")
        Button("change StateObject"){stateObject.s.append("_x")}
        Button("change State"){if state == nil {
          state = "state"} else{
            state?.append("_y")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct SubView: View {
  @Binding var selected: Int?
  @State var selectedLocal : Int?
  var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
      List(values, id: \.self, selection: $selectedLocal) { val in
        Text("\(val)")
      }
    }    
  }
}


class SimpleStateObject: ObservableObject {
  @Published var s = "stateObject"
}
```

Interestingly, the @State and the @StateObject are shared in an
iPad App in split mode.

Comment: You can use AppStorage for little stuff and any storage for anything else

Comment: You are creating an instance of the SimpleStateObject inside the view so of course it will not be shared between the views. For anything to be shared you need to inject an instance from the outside

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs? It doesn't sound right to me

Answer (score 0):

> I want to share state between multiple windows of the same SwiftUI app on Mac.

Use `@EnvironmentObject`, `@Environment`, `@ObservedObject`, or `@Binding`, as appropriate. If the state is actually some complex collection of objects, it might be appropriate to store the data using Core Data, in which case each window might have its own `@FetchRequest` into the same data store, which is another way to share state.